# Windows move .git folder other place

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project C:\Work\Project

With .git C:\Work\Project.git

I want keep project in C:\Work\Project

But move .git to **D:**\Work\Project.git

I try use mklink **mklink /d c:\Work\Project.git d:\WORK\Project.git**

But SourceTree not work with error **'git status' failed with code 128: fatal: Invalid symlink 'c:\Work\Project.git': Function not implemented**

I don`t want multiple folders.

I want keep repositories on other drive from code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple working directories with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git)

Comment: The `.git` folder is the actual code repository. Your project folder is the working directory, ie your current working copy of the files. You are asking how to use a different working directory. The duplicate question shows some possibilities but this is fragile. Why do you want to separate the repo from your working directory?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1. I want keep .git folder on other drive 2. .git folder contain more 2000 files and i don`t want it on drive with code. 3. symlink is good but not work

Comment: But *why*? To save space? A repo with many files (2000 is *not* a lot) doesn't affect the disks performance, as they are mostly read-only (git doesn't alter stored objects, it creates diff objects)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use SSD. And faced with the fact that the SSD may refuse without notice. I always installed SSD + HDD. SSD - to work, HDD - data

Comment: Then you should be pushing to a "backup" bare repo, not try to separate the repo from the working directory. You can create a hook to push changes to another local repo (second HDD, an external USB drive, a file share, or all of them) and a hosted repo just to be sure. That would give you real security for minimal cost

Comment: Imagine the "kid spilled milk on laptop and pushed it over the table" scenario. Multiple remotes with hooks will save you when separating the working directory can't